# phpunit does not find included class

Tags: php, phpunit

For a given project I have two php files to run php unittests, which are located in subdirectories.

The first file (`AllTestSuite.php`) looks like this:

```
<?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/unittest.inc.php';

class AllTestsSuite {
    public static function suite(){
        return new GlobTestsSuite(dirname(__FILE__), "/*/*Suite.php");
    }
}

?>
```

and the second file (`unittest.inc.php`) looks like this:

```
<? 
class GlobTestsSuite extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite {

    public function __construct($sDirectory, $sExpression){
        parent::__construct();
        foreach (glob("$sDirectory/$sExpression") as $sTest){
            require_once($sTest);
            $this->addTestSuite(basename($sTest, ".php"));
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The tests itself are invoked (on Ubuntu, `phpunit` Version 3.7.27) as follows:

```
phpunit   AllTestsSuite ./AllTestsSuite.php
```

which gives the error message

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'GlobTestsSuite' not found in /home/.../AllTestsSuite.php on line 6
```

I do not understand what is going here. The file `AllTestsSuite.php` imports the other file in which the class `GlobTestSuite` is defined. How to fix this problem?

Comment: What is the reason for this unusual test call and require usage?

Comment: @SenseException: I cannot tell you. I only got this project with the unittests 'as-is'. I am not allowed to make major changes.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but found a similar problem with PHPUnit, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29232027/phpunit-cannot-find-source-code?noredirect=1#comment46670144_29232027